# How to deobfuscate R8 Stack traces?

Tags: android, obfuscation, deobfuscation, android-r8

I have an app and it crashes just like every good app should!
A little while ago, the Android build tools started using *R8* instead of *Proguard*. It worked and it sped up my build, so I left it alone. Then came an exception stack trace that I had to deobfuscate. I used the proguard UI, The `retrace.bat` script, and the commandline, but the supposedly deobfuscated stack trace still looked obfuscated.

Looking at the `mapping.txt` generated, I see a bunch of numbers (line numbers?) in the mapping that I don't recall having seen before. I suspect these are the reason why the deobfusctaors above all fail.

Is there any way to currently deobfuscate such stack traces?

Also posted as https://issuetracker.google.com/137078989

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please make sure to download the latest version of ProGuard from https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/ to get a version of retrace which will work with the R8 mapping files.

If that still does not produce the correct stack trace file a new bug (or update the existing).

Comment: Yeah that's the answer I got from Google. Should have updated this post. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed. I had an issue with proguard v4.7 included in Android sdk tools. Proguard v6.2.0 worked fine. For macOS users: you can install proguard directly by running `brew install proguard`; to check existing version run `proguard` with no arguments. In case you don't have it in your path, try to run `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/bin/proguard.sh`